# Linux always send ICMP redirect

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I have several Debian Squeeze (6.0.6 up to date) used as routers.
When a link is down, they send ICMP redirects to local hosts. This is the default behaviour of Debian and several others. So once the link comes back to life, the hosts can't reach it until reboot.

I don't want any ICMP redirect to be sent from those routers.

I tested `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/send_redirects` and `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0` and putting `net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0` into `/etc/sysctl.d/local.conf`
Every of those solution put the right value into `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/send_redirects`

But...
the kernel keep sending ICMP redirects. Even after a reboot :

```
$ tcpdump -n -i eth0
00:56:17.186995 IP 192.168.0.254 > 192.168.0.100: ICMP redirect 10.10.13.102 to host 192.168.0.1, length 68
```

And the routing table of local hosts (Windows computers) are polluted.

I can prevent this with netfilter :
`iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p icmp --icmp-type redirect -j DROP`

Any idea about why the usual method doesn't work ?
And how to prevent ICMP redirect to be sent, without using netfilter ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The right command is : `echo 0 | tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/send_redirects`
Because you must have 0 on 'all' and on 'interface_name' to disable it.

Into `/etc/sysctl.conf` or similar file, you have to set 'all' + 'default' (or 'all' + 'interface' but the interface may not exists already when this file is processed).

Comment: What's the point of the "all" directory then? I had the vague impression, it would overwrite the values of all other entries?

Comment: @Elrond, `all` doesn't overwrite, it does bitwise operations. See [this answer about `all` vs. `default`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90560/13004). `send_redirects` is an `OR` parameter, so setting `all.send_redirects` to 0 will be trumped by the interface's setting.