# Kernel /proc ipv6 settings precedence

Tags: linux-kernel, proc, ipv6

I'm about to connect our network to the IPv6 Internet and need to control the kernel ipv6 settings found under `/proc`. I know there are configurations for each interface, for `all` interfaces, and the `default` config. My question is: which settings win if the individual values contradict each other? While I was able to find good documentation on the individual settings, I don't know about setting precedence ...

There is a [related question concerning IPv4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90560/19575), but it mainly talks about the differences of `all`, `default` and the individual interfaces.  From that I gather the concrete settings are always somehow logically combined. However, the fields most important to me (see the following examples) are not covered, and IPv6 seems to be implemented differently so that the referenced kernel source file in the referenced answer does not help my IPv6 issue and the following examples.

A few examples:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_ra
0
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth1/accept_ra
1
```

Will eth1 accept router advertisements?

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding
1
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth1/forwarding
0
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth1/accept_ra
1
```

Will eth1 accept router advertisements?

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
1
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_ra
1
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth1/disable_ipv6
0
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_ra
0
```

Will eth1 accept router advertisements?

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
1
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/fowarding
1
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth1/disable_ipv6
0
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_ra
1
```

Will eth1 accept router advertisements?

Comment: `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
1` that soesn't sound like IPv6 is activated

Comment: @Kiwy Isn't that the point of the question? It's about what happens when things are disabled in `/all` but enabled for individual interfaces

Answer (score 2):

1. yes
2. yes
3. depends
4. depends

The "default" entries are, well, the default.  When an interface comes up, it inherits the parameters from there.

The "all" entries are there to assign a parameter to all interfaces at once.  That does not mean that every interface is locked to that parameter.  For instance, consider

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_ra
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp2s1/accept_ra
```

then

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_ra
0
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp2s1/accept_ra
1
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp2s0/accept_ra
0
```

so "all" does not represent any kind of state, it is only for collective assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting, i had a similar issue wrapping my head around the *forwarding* parameter.

In IPv4 you can forward on some interfaces. That is useful especially on multihomed hosts where you want to keep some of the subnets on internal interfaces really private. You can also activate forwarding for all interfaces by using `.../all/forwarding` and you can define a default value to be set for any interface coming up later. That's all ok but ...

In IPv6 this behavior is indeed different. I'd set the `forwarding=1` for some of my IPv6 interfaces without setting `../all/forwarding=1` and was surprised that no forwarding happened at all. The kernel param manual says the following:

> 11.2.3.5. forwarding
>
> Type: BOOLEAN
>
> Default: FALSE if global forwarding is disabled (default), otherwise TRUE
>
> Configure interface-specific Host/Router behaviour.    Note: It is
>   recommended to have the same setting on all interfaces; mixed
>   router/host scenarios are     rather  uncommon. [...]

So setting `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding=1` is *mandatory* to get it working, and that sounds logical because the host can be either only a router (No router soliciations, router advs & redirects are ignored) or just a plain host (accepting router advs & autoconf) but not both at the same time or at least can't behave different on a selection of interfaces that makes the difference to IPv4

Although the term `all` is very confusing here and should be replaced by `enabled` because once you set that on IPv6 you can clear forwarding on one or more of the other interfaces to be excluded from forwarding!
So the condition for `all` isn't met anymore. Now i would expect that if you clear one of them then `all` gets cleared too? ... but to my surprise that's not the case!

The Question seems to be if `all` overrides any of the other `forwarding` settings then

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp2s1/forwarding
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/enp2s2/forwarding
```

can't be true at the same time when `all` is mandatory, from my point of view it's simply a contradiction!

Comment: That's at least some information on the forwarding parameter. I suppose one of these days I will just have to try it out.

Comment: conf/all/forwarding can be better understood as `1 = enabled` `2 = disabled`